# Difference installing Docker from Ubuntu Repository and Official Docker Repository?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-image

I have found this post for installing Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver which shows two different ways of doing it.

Besides the slightly different steps and commands you need to follow, what is the difference between installing Docker from the Ubuntu Repository and from the Official Docker Repository? Does anyone give a more stable version?

And also what is the difference between the `edge` and `nightly` repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you get a package from the Ubuntu Repository, it is an older version than the official repository for that package. The reason for this is that the Ubuntu Repository has spent some time making sure all their packages work together, and that two packages, installed together don't mess each other up. By the time that the new version of the repository is released, the official version of the package has probably been updated a few times.

Nightly repositories have packages that are built regularly, usually daily (hence the name). Edge repositories, on the other hand, have packages that are built after some finished change. They have not had bug-fixes yet, so if you are using them, you might run into a few bugs.

EDIT: If you get a package from the Ubuntu Repositories, it is more likely to run compatibly with other packages from the Ubuntu Repositories than if you get the package from the package's official repository. Therefore, this version is recommended unless you need some new feature that isn't included in the version.

EDIT: I would not recommend nightly repositories in any case. From what I understand, it is meant solely to keep a kind of log. I would recommend using stable repositories, since that will have a lot of the bugs fixed.

Comment: Ok, so `nightly` is preffered than `edge` reposritories in case of Docker Repositories. But is it better to install Docker from the Docker Repository or the Ubuntu one, even if it has an older version?

Comment: I'm sorry. Nightly is not meant to be used at all. It will have more bugs than edge. Stable is preferred. As for which is better, it really depends. I would use the one from Ubuntu, as long as you aren't counting on some new feature.